# Restore delta table to previous version after creating a copy of version with current date in databricks

Tags: python, databricks, delta-lake

I want to restore previous version of delta table by creating its copy first with copy job run date folder name  and then restore delta table using that copy file

Any suggestion here.

Here's what I'm trying:

```py
version_timestamp = dbutils.widgest.get("widget_name")
var1= "SELECT version FROM (describe history dbname.tablename) where to_timestamp(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') = '"+version_timestamp+"'" 
version=spark.sql(var1).collect()
```

If version == version_timestamp it creates new folder and writes else fails

Comment: Can you please add some more details to this question?  Here is the documentation for the RESTORE command: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-restore.html. What have you tried?  Did the command cause you any issues?

Comment: @Powers ,yes i am using delta lake documentation .
  My aprroach is read version from delta file and create a new folder based on version and then to restore using it.
 version_timestamp = dbutils.widgest.get("widget_name")
 var1= "SELECT version FROM (describe history dbname.tablename) where to_timestamp(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') = '"+version_timestamp+"'"
 version=spark.sql(var1).collect()
 If version == version_timestamp
  it creates new folder and writes
  else
  fails

Comment: I don't think you normally need to copy data when restoring to a previous version.  That's one of the benefits of versioned data.  Suppose you have a dataset with v1, v2, and v3.  If you restore to v2, then you can still access v3.  So perhaps in your particular case, copying the data is needed, but I would usually recommend against this.

Comment: yes you are right delta has that feature already where you can time travel and restore but this additional requirement is in my usecase

Comment: Does the answer provided by matkurek solve your issue?  If so, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create folder with backup, adjust added date to whatever else you want:

```
import datetime
path = 'dbfs:/mnt/your_dataset_path'
bck_path= path +'_backup_'+datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    
dbutils.fs.cp(path, bck_path)
```

Then restore using time travel, either using the backup path or the original:

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/mnt/your_dataset_path')  # path-based tables, or
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, 'table-name')    # Hive metastore-based tables

deltaTable.restoreToVersion(0) # restore table to oldest version

deltaTable.restoreToTimestamp('2022-09-14') # restore to a specific timestamp
```